# 403 from deployed Firebase function

Tags: firebase, url-rewriting, google-cloud-firestore, http-status-code-403

I have a Firebase function `/getshared` that works under `firebase serve`. The deployed function however gives me this error in the web browser:

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /getshared/getshared from this server.
```

Note that `/getshared` is doubled in the error message.

Another function works both locally and deployed.

I have tried to guess what is wrong, but I can't see any abvious differences between the two functions. I am very unsure about the rewrite rules and a bit suspicious of them, but the rewrite ruls in `firebase.json` looks similar:

```
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/getshared",
            "function": "getshared"
        }
```

Any suggestions for what I should look for to find out what is wrong?

---

There is an issue that talks about regions and 403, but I do not think it applies. I am just viewing this in the web browser. But I do not understand this so I am not sure:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/842

---

### EDIT1

After asking (above) for things that were obviously wrong I followed the advice from Doug S to try to nail the problem down.

So I first copied the file with function that did not work, renamed the function and added the necessary entries in `index.js` and `firebase.json`. To my surprise the copied function worked.

So I went back to the original function and tried some renaming. It turned out that renaming the function exported in `index.js` from `getshared` to `getshared1` made everything work as expected. This is the only change needed to make things work (in `index.js`):

```
// exports.getshared = sharedEdit.getShared;
exports.getshared1 = sharedEdit.getShared;
```

Plus the corresponding name change in `firebase.json`, of course:

```
            "source": "/getshared",
            "function": "getshared1"
```

I am using VS Code for this project. I have searched the whole project for "getshared", but can't find anything suspicious. (Hm, does the search exclude something?)

At the moment I am guessing this is a problem in Firebase. But I am not sure.

Comment: Please edit the question such that anyone can fully reproduce.  This means sharing your code and configurations, and the exact command you're using to run the emulator.  Also it seems that you're expecting Firebase Hosting to proxy a URL to the function - please be clear if that is the case.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks, please see EDIT1 above.

Comment: Still not enough information here.  Please provide everything necessary to reproduce the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson I am sorry. I can't reproduce it with a simple example. And I am out of ideas for what is going on. I can't even reproduce it with a copied file.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hm, though I just noticed something when testing locally (`firebase serve`). It normally works very nicely when testing functions, I do not have to restart the server. But because I edited "firebase.json" to try to reproduce the error I noticed that editing this file requires a restart of the local server. So I wonder if cashing of "firebase.json" has something to do with the error I started this question with.

Comment: I don't know.  You do have to restart the emulator if you change firebase.json.

Comment: @DougStevenson I still don't know how to reproduce the problem, but I just got hit by the same problem for another URL (in the same project).